# How to install recharts with react v18?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I try to install recharts in my app using react v 18. When I put `npm install recharts` in my terminal, it throws :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from recharts@2.1.9
```

Is there an other way to do it while the library gets updated or is it better to go back to the old version of react?

Here is my package.json:

```
    {
      "name": "project-name",
      "version": "0.1.0",
     
     "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "react": "^18.1.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "sass": "^1.51.0",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Thank you !

Comment: You could complement your question adding your package.json to make it more understandable for community help.

Comment: Yes of course, I just added it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run this command:

```bash
npm install recharts --force
```

But this can cause bugs as Recharts doesn't support react 18 for now. Another option is to use the previous version of React 17.0.2:

```bash
npm uninstall react react-dom
npm install react@17.0.2 react-dom@17.0.2
```

This way you guarantee that you won't have any problems, because recharts is fully compatible with React version 17.